# How to select multiple rows in Google Sheets and do a sort?

Tags: google-sheets

I found that if I select 20 rows in Google Sheets, and try to sort it by right clicking the range, there is no "Sort" option.

I have to select Cell A3 to AW22, which is a "range" or "region" and then right click, and sorting is possible.

But selecting all these rows actually is the same as selecting all these cells, because these 20 rows contain nothing but these cells. Is there a way to select some rows and sort?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still sort from the menu: `Data > Sort range ...`

The context menu offered on right-click contains some operations that users are likely to perform in the current context. When entire rows are selected, they are likely to do row operations like hiding/deleting/inserting, and those take the place of other operations like sort. This does not necessarily mean that those other things are no longer available; they just did not make the cut for inclusion in the current context menu.

Comment: this solves the problem, although selecting some rows and then sorting them is such a normal and common thing to do, so I don't understand why it wouldn't "make the cut"... but it is a subjective thing